# nvcc fatal : Value ‘sm_86’ is not defined for option ‘gpu-architecture'

Tags: nvidia, cuda, blender

when I try to install ProgressLabeller add-on in Blender2.92, I get the following error:

[image]

and my driver version and CUDA version is:

[image]

How can I solve the error? The possible reason for the same problem is CUDA Version mismatch the Driver version, but my version seems right.

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details.

Answer (score 0):

Its software error forcing GPU compute on value type not supported by CUDA toolkit, if your cuda toolkit is configured correctly you can check yourself values that are supported by the architecture

```
nvcc --help
```